# Use a generic pathway as default

Tags: vba, excel, userform, filesystemobject

I have a small program that creates a load of files and saves to a folder specified by the user. Currently the top of the `userform` looks like the following when initialised:

[image]

I'd prefer if when the userform opens and also when the dialog for choosing a appears (via the  Destination button) that a general default is already shown:

[image]

Can the program find the pathway to a user's desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the path to the users desktop, use:

```
PathToDesktop = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"
```

Comment: +1 hmmm - I've never seen `Environ` before - part of the `interaction` class

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in excel-vba, the following code would save the current workbook as a copy to the user's desktop... you can probably figure out what you're doing from there.

```
Dim DesktopPath As String 
DesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs DesktopPath & "filename.xls"
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the alternative to Manu's answer: his answer is a little more concise.